# Not able to get response from a URL

Tags: javascript, url, xmlhttprequest, request

I have spent hours in this problem and my fellows couldn't help me out. He said it might be a cross-site scripting problem, probably my system setting cause this problem because the script runs well on my fellow's machine.

Below is the simple case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/javascriptkit.json";
req.open("GET", url, false);
try {
    req.send();
} catch (e) {
    alert("ERROR: " + e);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Execute the code, an error shows up:

```
ERROR: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://firebug/content/console/commandLineExposed.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 156"  data: no]
```

I ran this code on my localhost, firebug console and jsFiddle, all of them are not working.

I am sure my local server is running well since the test script `alert("works")` is working.

Anyone can help me out here. Is this a system setting problem? Thanks!

Comment: Specify `null` in `HTTP`'s body ->   `req.send(null);`

Comment: what's this for? not same as `req.send()`? I dont quite get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` to a different domain? Unless they set a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in their response, you won't be able to get at it. In Opera (well, version 11.64 at least), you won't be able to get at it, regardless.

I think your colleague's machine is insecurely configured.

Comment: Thanks. My first time use XMLHttpRequest, not aware of this restriction. I find someone to access me to the server like my colleague, now I can get the data I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot make a cross domain call like this.

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest is subject to the browser's same origin policy in that, for security reasons, requests will only succeed if they are made to the same server that served the original web page.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a proxy to retrieve external content.

As demonstrated on: http://icant.co.uk/articles/crossdomain-ajax-with-jquery/using-proxy.html. Here, they make the external request from a PHP page and use it in the javascript function call.

Here's the link to the home for the demo page: http://icant.co.uk/articles/crossdomain-ajax-with-jquery/index.html